# Call by Value in Grails function?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

Assume that I have an object:

```
def user = User.get(someId)
```

Now I want to execute the following:

```
myFunction(user.id)
user.delete(flush: true)
```

1. Is the argument of myFunction call-by-value, i.e., does the function gets only the value of user.id and not the reference?
2. What if the user was deleted before myFunction has finished? Is the value user.id still available in myFunction?

Comment: You can test it yourself. Modify user in `myFunction` and print it before deleting user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer that question you need to know the languages that the framework is build in, in this case `Groovy & Java`.

Knowing that it's [easy to find](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Passing+Values+by+Reference+%28in-out%29) the documentation that explains how the language works (note that, despite by the title, the first paragraph explains that is "pass-by-value").

And [here](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm) it's a more detailed explanation.